# What is the minimum workspace role that implicitly gives build permission on the dataset (and also doesn't break RLS)?

Tags: powerbi

Power BI workspace has 4 roles: Admin, Member, Contributor and Viewer.

There is a report and dataset in this workspace. I want to allow a user to build his own reports, but the user has currently not got any permission on the workspace.

Option 1 is to give the build permission on the dataset level. Option 2 is to give workspace permission - maybe contributor or higher?

1. What workspace role implicitly gives an user the `build` permission on the dataset in the workspace?
2. If an user is assigned with workspace role higher than viewer, then RLS no longer works on the dataset so option 1 is the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, RLS is not enforced for Workspace roles other than Viewer.

Comment: What workspace role implicitly gives an user the build permission on the dataset in the workspace?

Comment: Contributor.  Although that only allows you to build reports in the current workspace.  To build a report in a different workspace from the dataset still requires Build permission on the dataset.  This is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-roles-new-workspaces

Comment: So if I give contributor permission to the report and dataset workspace then it implicitly gives build permission on dataset. The problem is it will break RLS, yes?

Comment: RLS is not enforced for workspace contributors.